# MOQ create a mock object that accepts 8 arguments and returns a boolean

Tags: c#, moq

I'm trying to create a mock object for interface INotificationService and set it up so that the method PushNotification (accepts 8 arguments) will always return true or false.

The below seems to not work as expected.

Do I need to use the Callback method as well, to do this?

```
        var notificationServiceMock = new Mock<INotificationService>();
        notificationServiceMock
            .Setup(n => n.PushNotification(
                It.IsAny<long>(), 
                It.IsAny<Guid>(), 
                It.IsAny<string>(), 
                It.IsAny<string>(), 
                It.IsAny<DateTime>(), 
                It.IsAny<string>(), 
                It.IsAny<decimal>(), 
                It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns<bool>(b => { return true; });
```

Comment: "The below seems to not work as expected" Then, how *does* it work? What do you get?

Comment: I think you want to use .Returns(true);

Comment: Thanks everyone, if you said my information is incomplete you are absolutely correct. I should have tried a bit longer before posting here. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var notificationServiceMock = new Mock<INotificationService>();

notificationServiceMock.Setup(n => n.PushNotification(
            It.IsAny<long>(), 
            It.IsAny<Guid>(), 
            It.IsAny<string>(), 
            It.IsAny<string>(), 
            It.IsAny<DateTime>(), 
            It.IsAny<string>(), 
            It.IsAny<decimal>(), 
            It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(true);

INotificationService ntfObj = notificationServiceMock.Object;
```